# How to (eval ...) in a chicken r7rs library?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme, r7rs

I am trying to get a basic `eval` to work within a library of the `r7rs` egg. The following *toplevel* (not library) program work as I expected, when run with `csi -R r7rs`:

```
(import (scheme base)
        (scheme eval))

(eval '42 (scheme-report-environment 5))
```

This works for `(null-environment 5)`, too (but not with the `(environment '(scheme base) ...)` variant by the way). However, within a library:

```
(define-library (test-eval)
  (import
    (scheme base)
    (scheme eval))
  (export
    my-eval)
  (begin
    (define (my-eval)
      (eval '42 (scheme-report-environment 5)))))
```

I get

```
Error: module unresolved: test-eval
....
<syntax>          [my-eval] (scheme-report-environment 5)
<syntax>          (##core#begin)
<syntax>          (##core#undefined)    <--
```

What could be the problem? It seems there were some issues with R7RS environments in the [Wiki](https://wiki.call-cc.org/r7rs-tasks#environments-and-evaluation), but I am not sure if that's related here.

Tested with chicken version 5.2.0 (homebrew package), both `csi` and `csc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked about this issue on the Chicken mailing list and immediately got help. First, for `scheme-report-environment`, there need to be an additional import

```
(import
   (scheme base)
   (scheme eval)
   (only (scheme r5rs) scheme-report-environment))
```

There were also two bugs in Chicken - which were fixed within one day (!) (see the [mailing list archive](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/chicken-users/2020-09/msg00008.html)). With version 1.0.3 of the `r7rs` egg, `eval` now works as expected within a library.